# Discrete logarithm problem - Pohlig Hellman $GF(2^{60})$

Tags: polynomials, discrete-logarithms

I would like to ask how to modify Pohlig Hellman algorithm if I need to work with polynomials $GF(2^{60})$ I know how this algorithm works with numbers, but I am not able to imagine how to do some operations with polynomials. E.g. if I need to do $g^{\frac{p-1}{q^e}}$. How can I do this with polynomial? I have found some similar question, but there is not a lot of information, and I didn't understand it.

$p = x^{60} + x^{59} + 1$,

$g = x$,

$h = x^{58} +x^{55} +x^{54} +x^{52} +x^{51} +x^{50} +x^{49} +x^{48} +x^{44} +x^{43} +x^{41} +x^{40} +x^{37} +x^{34} +x^{33} + x^{32} +x^{29} +x^{27} +x^{26} +x^{21} +x^{19} +x^{17} +x^{15} +x^{13} +x^{10} +x^9 +x^6 +x^5 +x^4 +x^2 +1$

$q = p - 1 = x^{60} + x^{59} = x^{59}*(x+1)$ (I am not sure if it is correct factorization)

$ e = 1 , 1$

Comment: Do you mean polynomials in $GF(2^{60})[X]?$ Or do you represent $a\in GF(2^{60})$ as polynomial? What are $g,p,q,e?$ Note that, if $p=60$ (as title and text suggest), then $p-1$ is prime, so what is $\frac{p-1}{q^e}?$ This question is even more unclear than your now deleted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2767968/pohlig-hellman-algoritmus-over-gf260

Comment: @gammatester Sorry, I don't understand what is unclear. I only don't know how this algorithm works, if I work with polynomials over GF (I know how it works over Z)  $a \in GF(2^{60})$ I have added to my question polynomials which I have if it helps, but I only want to know how it works. Doing something like this $x^{x}$ (polynomial^polynomial) is I think nonsense in this case

Comment: There are a few obvious confusions. Compare with [WP on Pohlig-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm). The order of the cyclic group in this DLP is $n=q-1=2^{60}-1$. You cannot use a polynomial in the exponent, so $p-1=x^{60}+x^{59}$ does not make any sense.

Comment: Then, you want to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem. To that end you need a factorization of $n$. Because $60$ is highly divisible, this is easy (I did consult Mathematica):
$$2^{60}-1=3^2\cdot5^2\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot31\cdot41\cdot61\cdot151\cdot331\cdot1321.$$ These are the $p_i^{e_i}$ quantities referred to in that WP-article.

Comment: It becomes more unclear. Is $p=60$ or is $p = x^{60} + x^{59} + 1?$ 
$GF(2^{^{60} + x^{59} + 1})$ is nonsense. I guess you represent the elements of $GF(2^{60})$ as polynomials modulo the irreducible  polynomial $p=x^{60} + x^{59} + 1$.
You multiply two elements of $GF(2^{60})$  by multiplying their polynomial representatives and compute the remainder mod $p(x)$ with the Euclidian algorithm.

Comment: Remember that the field $GF(2^{60})$ is constructed as the quotient ring
$$GF(2^{60})=GF(2)[x]/\langle x^{60}+x^{59}+1\rangle.$$ Effectively you are reducing the coefficients of the polynomials modulo $2$, AND also reducing the high degree polynomials modulo $x^{60}+x^{59}+1$.

Comment: Pohlig-Hellman calls you to calculate, for example, $g^{n/1321}$. Here $n=2^{60}-1$ so $n/1321=872764197279975$. So one of the preparatory steps is to calculate the remainder of
$$g^{n/1321}=x^{872764197279975}$$ modulo the defining polynomial $p(x)=x^{60}+x^{59}+1$. Not gonna do that here, but I will just remind you that [square-and-multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is your friend.

Comment: In other words, the $p-1$ in the Pohlig-Hellman for $GF(p)$ MUST NOT be replaced with $p(x)-1$ here. That parameter is the order of the group. So, it is an integer.  Here it is $2^{60}-1$ because the zero element of the field is not an element of the multiplicative group. That seems to have been a major source of confusion to you.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you very very much, I think that it is clear now :)